# I made a program while ago and i dont understand some parts of it . It's about lists

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I may miss something about pointers but I dont get why my code works 
I made a list and I got to insert new nodes (values) at the end of the list .

Here is the code of the function that I don't understand properly.
Just imagine we got to add 3 elements like 1 2 3

```
Tlist InsertAtEnd (Tlist head,int x) {
    Tnode *newNode, *tmp;
    newNode = makenode(x);
    tmp = head;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        while(tmp->next!=NULL) {
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = newNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```

So if I insert the first node it's all fine I understand the process. 
The problems comes at the second insertion.
It goes in the else and then it changes `tmp->next = newnode;`

I changed the value tmp-next with the value of newnode (which is the second node im adding) but as it is called tmp should be temporary .

I return head right? I changed nothing in head didn't I? but that's what makes me smh .

When it prints the values of the list it prints them correctly how's that possible. How do I make the linked list only changing the tmp values?

Comment: `TList` passed as value? or `typedef` to pointer? As `head` and `temp` are of two different types, you must have got compiler warnings for assignment operation.

Comment: Since you have not specified what TList stands fro, it is difficult to help i.e. if it is not a ** ptr then your function doesn twork since you can't change `head`

Comment: @AndersK function returns `head`, so doubly pointer is not necessary. But `TNode*` must be equal to `TList`

Comment: Going forward, work to avoid [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and work though [Singly Linked List](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB)

Comment: @TruthSeeker yep i see that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictures should help.  Not knowing how `Tlist` and `Tnode` are defined, I have to make some guesses, but based on the code it looks like they're defined something like this:

```
struct node { int value; struct node *next; };
typedef struct node Tnode;
typedef Tnode *Tlist;
```

Let's imagine you have an object in your code named `list`.  This object is a pointer to a `Tnode` type, and it initially is set to `NULL` (points "nowhere"):

```
      +---+
list: | +-+---|||
      +---+
```

We call `InsertAtEnd`, passing `list` as the `head` argument and the value `1` as `x`.  The first thing your function does is create a new node with that value (and I'm assuming it nulls out the `next` member):

```
         +---+     +---+---+
newNode: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---|||
         +---+     +---+---+
```

Since your list is initially empty, we set `head` to point to this new node:

```
      +---+
list: | +-+---||| // list is a distinct object from head
      +---+

      +---+     +---+---+
head: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+
                  ^
         +---+    |
newNode: | +-+----+
         +---+
```

Remember, the *value* of `head` is the *address* of the newly created node.

The code then returns `head`, which we'll assume is assigned back to `list`, giving us this:

```
      +---+     +---+---+
list: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+
```

Now we call `InsertAtEnd` again with `list` and the value `2`.  The first thing your code does is create the new node:

```
         +---+     +---+---+
newNode: | +-+---> | 2 | +-+---|||
         +---+     +---+---+
```

Now, since the list *isn't* empty, we use the temporary variable `tmp` that initially points to the same object as `head`:

```
      +---+
list: | +-+-------+
      +---+       |
                  V
      +---+     +---+---+
head: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+
                  ^
      +---+       |
 tmp: | +-+-------+
      +---+
```

When then iterate through the list until the `next` member of the thing `tmp` points to is `NULL`.  In this case, it's the first object of the list, so we set `tmp->next` to point to our new node:

```
      +---+
list: | +-+-------+
      +---+       |
                  V
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
head: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---> | 2 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
                  ^             ^
      +---+       |             |
 tmp: | +-+-------+             |
      +---+                     |
                                |
         +---+                  |
newNode: | +-+------------------+
         +---+
```

When we return from `InsertAtEnd`, our list looks like this:

```
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
list: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---> | 2 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
```

Now we call `InsertAtEnd` one more time, with `list` and the value `3`.  Again, we start by creating the new node:

```
         +---+     +---+---+
newNode: | +-+---> | 3 | +-+---|||
         +---+     +---+---+
```

Then we point `tmp` to the first element in the list, and "walk" down the list until `tmp->next` is `NULL`:

```
      +---+
list: | +-+-------+
      +---+       |
                  V
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
head: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---> | 2 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
                  ^
      +---+       |
 tmp: | +-+-------+   // tmp->next != NULL
      +---+
```

Second iteration:

```
      +---+
list: | +-+-------+
      +---+       |
                  V
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
head: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---> | 2 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
                                ^ 
      +---+                     |
 tmp: | +-+---------------------+   // tmp->next == NULL
      +---+
```

Again, we set `tmp->next` to point to the new node:

```
      +---+
list: | +-+-------+
      +---+       |
                  V
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
head: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---> | 2 | +-+---> | 3 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
                                ^             ^
      +---+                     |             |
 tmp: | +-+---------------------+             |
      +---+                                   |
                                              |
         +---+                                |
newNode: | +-+--------------------------------+
         +---+
```

and our list is now

```
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
list: | +-+---> | 1 | +-+---> | 2 | +-+---> | 3 | +-+---|||
      +---+     +---+---+     +---+---+     +---+---+
```

Hopefully that helps.

When I took Data Structures way, *way* back in the mid-Cretaceous, it took me about a week longer than my classmates to grok the concept of linked lists, so I feel you here.

Comment: i swear man you just great

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the temp->next value, on the second iteration(adding the second node) temp references the head and you add a new value with temp->next = newNode, which really does head->next = newNode. You always return the head, which doesn't change after the first insertion. The temporary variable references head, so the changes are persistent.

Answer (score 0):

The tail of singly linked list is last node which is pointing to nothing. While loop is iterating till the end of linked list( i.e until it finds the next node as NULL) and once the loop is exited `temp` is pointing to the last node on which newly created node is appended.

> I return head right? I changed nothing in head didnt i ?

Yes, indeed you are. But at the first insert you have created head and subsequent insert attached newly created node at the end of the tail(head itself is the tail for immediate next insert after head).